# 'the body politic' vs "the politic body"

Tags: grammaticality, legalese

According [hereto](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/politic), politic (with NO s) is an adjective or verb, and not a noun. So shouldn't [the body politic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/politic?show=1&t=1407248935) be "the politic body" instead? Are both legitimate? If so, what are the similarities and differences?

Source: p 186, The Legal Analyst, Ward Farnsworth

> We have been speaking of three usual parties to these situations:
>   the author of the rule, the enforcer of it, and the party to whom
>   it applies. But there may be a fourth party consisting of **the body politic**;
>   members of the public may take an interest in the law not because they
>   are concerned about how it applies to them personally but because they
>   are wondering if the law ought to be reformed.

Answer (score 4):

This type of adjective-noun inversion is not common, mostly encountered in writing and in fixed phrases. Here are a few examples that come to mind:

since **time immemorial** (meaning: since as far back as can be recalled)

the **body electric** (from a famous poem by Walt Whitman)

(interested in, well versed in, etc.) all **things political**, scientific, linguistic, French, etc.

Comment: Here I didn't count cases of passive participles commonly appearing after their noun: the word cited in my response; the question posed by the teacher; the chapter outlined in this lesson, etc.

Comment: There are more examples and discussion at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-positive_adjective

Comment: Cool. I had no idea what it was called :)