# Noun + anonymous examples

Tags: adjectives, word-order, nouns, postpositive-adjectives

What phrases are for "noun + anonymous"?

I've already found

- smokers anonymous
- alcoholics anonymous

Are they always used for places where people go to quit using something, or have other meanings?

Comment: The groups that are called noun + anonymous are probably using the same methodology for helping people to quit.  Some of them even have direct associations (Smokers Anonymous started by Alcholics Anonymous members.)  This is more a cultural thing than an English language thing.

Comment: @Kai , @DanGetz , `smokers anonymous` is in the picture of one of proverbs in `101 English proverbs` and I just wondered what it is.

Comment: @DanGetz could you please make that into an answer so that Kamtal can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are both names of organizations. There are many organizations with names that follow that pattern. The first was [Alcoholics Anonymous](http://www.aa.org) (AA), which is an organization to help alcoholics quit (and stay off of) alcohol. Other self-help organizations probably used similar names to draw parallels with AA. Many of these also use much of the same philosophy or methods, such as the "Twelve Steps". There's a list of such groups on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_twelve-step_groups). Some other examples from that page:

- Narcotics Anonymous
- Heroin Anonymous
- Overeaters Anonymous
- Workaholics Anonymous
- Online Gamers Anonymous

The phrase "alcoholics anonymous" literally means "anonymous alcoholics", that is, "alcoholics who are anonymous". In that phrase the adjective "anonymous" is used as a post-positive adjective. More information about these can be found in [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-positive_adjective) and [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/30814/).

Answer (score 1):

These are names of particular groups, i.e. they are *proper nouns*, and are capitalised, as in "Alcoholics Anonymous" (AA).

The original group of this type was "*Alcoholics Anonymous*".  This group was based around several key principals: only self-identified alcohols may join such a group;  members retain anonymity, they only disclose first names; they hold meetings which have a particular format, somewhat like a group confessional; the members agree to follow a 12-step programme under the guidance and coaching of a sponsor.

The way of running such a group is formalised in the ["*The 12 Traditions of Alcoholics Anonymous*" (link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Traditions)

There are now many such groups, each extending the model (or a variation of  it) to a new and different area of addictive or compulsive behaviour.

e.g. *Gamblers Anonymous*; *Narcotics Anonymous*; etc

There is a whole list of such groups at [Wikipedia's "*List of twelve-step groups*" (link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_twelve-step_groups)

They are all examples of "support groups".

One of AA's key steps is to surrender yourself to a higher power.   For some, this can be incompatible with personal beliefs, and there are [many support groups (link)](http://www.choosehelp.com/topics/recovery/don2019t-like-aa-6-community-meeting-alternatives-to-12-steps-groups) which have similar aims and objectives but which have a different approach to achieving them.